# How to extract all (also nested) key names with jq

Tags: json, jq

How can I extract all key names, even in nested objects with jq? 
For example,  I have json:

`{
 "a": 1,
  "b": {
      "c": 2
  }
}`

and I want to get list:
a, b, b.c

I know that for top level keys I can get this, with:
`. | to_entries[]  | .key`, but what about keys in nested objects?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Short **jq** solution:

```
jq -r '[paths | join(".")]'  jsonfile
```

The output:

```
[
  "a",
  "b",
  "b.c"
]
```

---

- `paths` function outputs the paths to all the elements in its input
- `join(".")` - to concatenate keys within hierarchical paths

Comment: Wow, it's so straightforward, I'm glad, that I've asked, thanks. I will only add that to avoid error: "string (".") and number (0) cannot be added" when there is array in json one should add mapping to string: `paths | map(.|tostring)|join(".")`

Comment: How does one modify this to get rid of the array indexes?

Comment: Replying to @CervEd's question, if your file's top level is an array, and you don't want to see those indices, you can use `'.[] | paths | join(".")'` for the `jq` program.

Answer (score 1):

Given input `foo.json`

```json
{"a":1,"b":[{"c":2}]}
```

```sh
jq '[
paths |
map(select(type!="number")) |
select(length > 0) |
join(".")
] | unique' foo.json
```

outputs

```
[
  "a",
  "b",
  "b.c"
]
```