# How to access nested json keys in jq --stream

Tags: json, jq

I have a huge json file(15 GB) which looks like as follows:

```
{
  "userActivities": {
    "-L3ATRosRd-bDgSmX75Z": {
      "deviceId": "60ee32c2fae8dcf0",
      "dow": "Friday"
    }
  },
  "users": {
    "0GTDyAepIjcKMB1XulHCYLXylFS2": {
      "ageRangeMin": 21,
      "age_range": {
        "min": 21
      },
      "gender": "male"
    },
    "0GTDyAepIjcKMB1S2": {
      "ageRangeMin": 22,
      "age_range": {
        "min": 20
      },
      "gender": "male"
    }
  }
}
```

I want to extract the objects as if by `.users[]`, but using the streaming parser (`jq --stream`). That is, I want my output to be as follows:

```
{"ageRangeMin":21,"age_range":{"min":21},"gender":"male"}
{"ageRangeMin":22,"age_range":{"min":20},"gender":"male"}
```

Any guidance/help is greatly appreciated. I'm unable to understand how `jq --stream` works.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46565894/4682460 for accessing nested keys in general

Answer (score 0):

If the goal is to just get objects at a certain depth of the json object tree, you can just truncate the stream.

```
$ jq --stream -nc 'fromstream(2|truncate_stream(inputs | select(.[0][:1] == ["users"])))'
```

Just make sure you're running the latest available jq. There's a bug in 1.5 for `truncate_stream/1` that breaks for any other input greater than `1`.

Comment: marcado your command does not gives the output. I'm using the below jq version "jq-1.5-1-a5b5cbe". Also, when I tried using 1, I got the output with keys like: "0GTDyAepIjcKMB1XulHCYLXylFS2": {
      "ageRangeMin": 21,
      "age_range": {
        "min": 21
      },
      "gender": "male"
    } However, I do not want the keys and ended up with the below command. Kindly suggest if it's ok to run on a very large json file: jq -cn --stream ' fromstream(1|truncate_stream(inputs|select((.[0][0] == "userActivities")| not)))' | jq -cn --stream ' fromstream(1|truncate_stream(inputs))

Comment: You'll have to build from source or download from appveyor. I'm assuming you're running Windows so you can get from [here](https://ci.appveyor.com/project/stedolan/jq).

Answer (score 0):

With your input in input.json, the following invocation:

```
$ jq -nc --stream '
  fromstream(inputs|select(.[0][0] == "users"))|.[][]' input.json
```

yields:

```
{"ageRangeMin":21,"age_range":{"min":21},"gender":"male"}
{"ageRangeMin":22,"age_range":{"min":20},"gender":"male"}
```

The idea is to extract the "users" key-value pair first as a single-key object.

Note that the -n option must be used here.